# Install WhatsApp on Android running under Virtualbox

Tags: installation, whatsapp-messenger, virtualbox

I've just installed Android using Virtualbox on Ubuntu, and now I want to install WhatsApp on it.

When I visit Google Play and try to install WhatsApp, it tells me that I have to associate a device via my Gmail account. When I'm connected, it's saying that I have to choose another device (because I've already installed it on my Nexus) but it doesn't list me the Virtualbox install as an option.

What's causing this problem?

Comment: Doesn't whatsapp need a SIM card?

Comment: yes of course ! But i've created it on the installation of the Android OS

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the Google Play app (or Google's services framework) on your VirtualBox install. You cannot download apps directly from the website, you must have the Android app installed if you want to get the Whatsapp from Google Play.

Comment: Have you tried getting the apk from another source?

Comment: as of 2019 this is easy. One can install WhatsApp via Playstore in Android/LineageOS (https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/releases) in VirtualBox. When Starting WhatsApp first time it asks for the phone number, which can be another phone. The sms will be sent there and you can type the code into the VM

Answer (score 3):

I was able to install Android on Virtualbox normally but never got Whatsapp working on it, always errors and complications (Tablets are not supported, etc...). Finally I found the only solution that worked for me on a [spanish website](http://www.htcmania.com/showthread.php?t=420902). NO SIM-card needed! Also beginners will understand!

Here's the way I did it:

1. Download Virtualbox for your system, install it...
2. Download Android with Whatsapp included [Android_4.1.1_WhatsApp.ova](https://hotfile.com/dl/187397473/86846cf/Android_4.1.1_WhatsApp.ova.html).
   This is a fully working Android version with Whatsapp already installed
3. If downloaded, open Virtualbox and

   - Select "File"-Menu
   - "Import Appliance..."
   - "Open appliance"
   - locate the downloaded "Android_4.1.1_WhatsApp.ova", select it and press "Open"
   - "Continue"
   - "Import"

Now you should have a Virtual Machine in vbox named "androVM_vbox86t_4.1.1_r4-20121002-gapps".
Select it and press "Start". A window with running Android will pop up, let it load, unlock it (if cursor doesn't work, disable in "Machine"-Menu the "Mouse Integration")

Your Android version will be in spanish language. With translate.google.com you will be able to select your own language in the settings menu in Android. 
Whatsapp is already installed, just run it and type a number you can be called with... Follow the steps and there you go.

Hope I could help you, I'm German, apologize for bad english ;)

Comment: A user suggested trying "http://uploadingit.com/file/view/xsqwzsfvfzaab0p0/Android_4.1.1_WhatsApp.ova" as a new download link since the current one doesn't work, use at your own risk though!

Comment: Where does the ova file originate from and how to be sure that this is not malware/has malware included?

Answer (score 2):

WhatsApp requires a SIM-Card as stated in a comment already. I know from various xda-developers discussions, that it's easier to do a backup from whatsapp on your phone with titanium backup, and then restore it inside your VM. Beware: the message database is local and messages are not synced across identical accounts.

Comment: as of 2019 that is not true anymore. One can install WhatsApp via Playstore in Android/LineageOS (https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/releases) in VirtualBox. When Starting WhatsApp first time it asks for the phone number, which can be another phone. The sms will be sent there and you can type the code into the VM

Answer (score 0):

1. Download & Install Virtualbox.
2. Download & Install Android version.
3. Download whatsapp application in your host machine.
4. Copy Whatsapp Application to your pen drive.
5. Attach Pen drive to your virtual machine.
6. Go-to File Manager.

There you can find your pen drive. Access Your Pen drive and install whatsapp or any application you copy in your pen drive.

Comment: Could you mention the links for the said applications?