# Install WhatsApp on Android x86 virtual machine

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, virtualbox

I installed [android-x86-6.0-r3.iso](https://www.fosshub.com/Android-x86.html/android-x86-6.0-r3.iso) on

```
$ virtualbox -help
Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 5.1.22_Ubuntu
```

using:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

If I open Play Store app and select WhatsApp, there is no option to install it. Only the option "add to wishlist" appears.

Is it possible to install WhatsApp via Play Store app on Android x86 virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way for installing WhatsApp for virtual device from Google Playstore.

- Android x86 doesn't come with all features (core features e.g play services, services framework etc) and SIM functionality is also missing.
- The virtual device being treated as as "tablet" is incompatible, as WhatsApp states:

> Tablet devices are not supported

There are workarounds however [to install it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25654/install-whatsapp-on-android-running-under-virtualbox) on the virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread [Install WhatsApp on Android running under Virtualbox](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25654/install-whatsapp-on-android-running-under-virtualbox) .

You could also try the Bluestacks Android Emulator. Easier setup and you can download any app from the Google Play Store including Whats app. Genymotion (free version) is also another good one.